# coldfusion splitting a loop with an include

Tags: loops, coldfusion, include

Here is some code:

```
<!---this is identical in several programs --->
<cfset i = 0>
<cfoutput>
   <cfloop array = "#colvalue#" index = "val">
      <cfset i = i + 1> 
      <cfset fieldname = colarr[i]>
      <cfset modnum = i%basenum>
      <script>
         putval2('#val#', '#i#')
      </script> 

 <!--- stuff which is different in each program --->

 </cfloop>
 </cfoutput>
```

This is working fine.

I put the identical code into a separate module called putback.cfm and rewrote this as:

```
<cfinclude template = "putback.cfm">

<!---stuff which is different in each program --->

</cfloop>
```

I got the error message "No matching start tag for end tag [cfloop]".

I thought the include meant that "putback.cfm" would be picked up and dumped into that spot in the program.  But since it is not recognizing that the end tag cfloop goes with with beginning cfloop in putback.cfm, apparently it is not as transparent a process as I have understood.

Can anyone explain why this is not working and/or offer a workaround.

Comment: ColdFusion does not work that way. ColdFusion uses nested structures. Your `</cfloop>` needs to match a `<cfloop>` that that is at the same nesting level.

Comment: Be careful of the unscoped `i` iterator, especially with a file that's being included in other pages. You could easily end up with `i` not having the value you think it's supposed to have. What are `collarr[]` and `basenum`? Are the values in the loop being used inside `putVal()`?  You may not need the loop at all depending on what your overall code is doing. What version of CF?

Comment: @Shawn It looks like the code was switching from CFML to Javascript. It make me look twice too.

Comment: @JamesAMohler Yeah, just saw that. But now I'm even more curious as to what `modnum` does. :-)

Comment: James: Good to know about the nested structures -- that explains a lot.  Yes, there is a javascript module included -- the approach works well all over the place.  Shawn: the "i" is in the variables scope.  I can't see how that would change due to an included module.  I can't think how the loop could be avoided, since I have to do something with each individual value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I thought the include meant that "putback.cfm" would be picked up and dumped into that spot in the program.

Close, but includes are placed and processed at runtime only. You are not reaching that point because of an expression error (by the CFML parser).

> it is not recognizing that the end tag cfloop goes with with beginning cfloop in putback.cfm

The parser runs through your .cfm templates to build the [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) before executing any code (runtime). The loop is never closed according to the parser because the include, which is another .cfm template, is inspected separately and never touched in its included state(s).

## The Fix

`<!--- stuff which is different in each program --->` is the part that should be included instead. However, this kind of coding practice is considered bad and eventually leads to [Spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code) as you require, reuse and depend on variables inside of the loop. Your include should not be aware of its surroundings. If you absolutely have to do it this way, at least use [cfmodule](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-m-o/cfmodule.html) to pass variables to your include.

The proper way of solving this problem is by using an interface. You specify what you need, provide what you have and let `<!--- stuff which is different in each program --->` serve this interface. This code structure would be based on [cfcomponent](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-c/cfcomponent.html) and its [cffunction](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-f/cffunction.html)s, implementing [cfinterface](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-i/cfinterface.html).

Comment: This is very helpful.  I was unaware of the AST and the way the cfinclude really works, and I will check out the interface approach.  I abhor spaghetti code.